# No. of values of $n$ such that $n \leq 1000$ and $n^2+7n+1$ is divisible by $33$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I have a problem and I have got stuck in it. The problem states that

Find the no. of integral values of $n$ such that $n^2+7n+1$ is divisible by $33$ and $1\leq n\leq1000$

What I did :

$$n^2+7n+1=33k$$$$n^2+7n+1-33k=0$$$$n=\frac{-7\pm\sqrt{45+132k}}{2}$$ since $n$ is integer $$45+132k=m^2$$ for some integer $m$

LHS is a multiple of $3$ so it has to be a multiple of $9$ to be a perfect square.

Now I am left with $$5+44x=m^2$$ where $k=3x$ and $x$ must end with $1,0,4,5,6,9$

Now I tried some values for $x$ to make LHS a prefect square and some solutions were $n=7,19,40,52...$

But I can't do it till $1000$

How to get it mathematically? My friend suggested me to do it with the help of congruences, But I am not so strong at using them.

If anyone can explain how it can be handled with congruences, it would be appreciated...

Comment: Since you found the $2$ solutions less then $33$ which are $7,19$ the rest are $7+33k$ and $19+33k$ for each $k$,now you're left to isolate those numbers which are between $1$ and $1000$. Also there seems to be more then $37$ solutions.

Comment: for $45+132k=m^2$ we have four positive integer solutions, $k=3,15,57,93$ and $m=21,45,87,111$.

Comment: @Ahmad If I would say there are more than 4 , then....???

Comment: @AtulMishra actually there are infinitely many in general, i just posted the four special  cases

Comment: @Ahmad Exactly , But I want to know how to reach them....... and upper limit does not go infinity ,, it is 1000 only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given equation is equivalent with $(2n+7)^2=132k+45$.  It follows that $2n+7=0 \ (3)$, hence $$n=3n_1-2\tag{1}$$ and $k=3k_1$. This leads to $(6n_1+3)^2=396k_1+45$, or
$$(2n_1+1)^2=44k_1+5\ .$$
This implies $(2n_1+1)^2=5 \ (11)$, or $2n_1+1=\pm4 \ (11)$. The latter can be rewritten as $n_1=11n_2+5\pm2$. Plugging this into $(1)$ gives
$$n=33n_2+13\pm6\ .$$
So far this is only a necessary condition on $n$. But it is easily checked that $7$ and $19$ satisfy the original equation, and $n\rightsquigarrow n+33$ transforms solutions into solutions. It follows that the solution set $S$ in question is given by
$$S=\{33n_2+7\ |\ 0\leq n_2\leq 30\}\cup\{33n_2+19\ |\ 0\leq n_2\leq29\}\ ,$$
and consists of $61$ elements.

Comment: This is the nicest solution of this question,, very helpful,, thanks@christian

Answer (score 2):

O.K. I will give a complete answer , for the equation $45+132k=m^2$ we have that

$k=132 c_1^2-42 c_1+3\land m=132 c_1-21$ or $k=132 c_1^2-90 c_1+15\land m=132 c_1-45$ or $k=132 c_1^2-174 c_1+57\land m=132 c_1-87$ or $k=132 c_1^2-222 c_1+93\land m=132 c_1-111$.

For which the corresponding $n$ is $n=66c_1 -14,-26,-47,-59$ for all $c_1 \geq 1$.

So listing all $n$ which fulfill your conditions we get that $n=\{7,19,40,52,73,85,106,118,139,151,172,184,205,217,238,250,271,283,304,316,337,349,370,382,403,415,436,448,469,481,502,514,535,547,568,580,601,613,634,646,667,679,700,712,733,745,766,778,799,811,832,844,865,877,898,910,931,943,964,976,997\}$

Which is easily compute able in brute force way.

Comment: But 179 is satisfying it which is not listed in your list

Comment: @AtulMishra no it doesn't !